# Dynamically resize brower height according to content

Tags: jquery, browser, resize, jquery-ui-accordion

As the title says, is it possible to dynamically resize the browser according to content? I'm using jquery accordion. Each 'accordion' is of a different height/length and I'd like to have the browser window to resize to each one.

e.g.: if all the accordions are closed then the browser would be at it's smallest and then resize to the selected accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't resize the browser window unless you created the window with `window.open()`, at which point you could use `window.resizeTo()` or `window.resizeBy()`.  Older browsers might have let you, but not anymore.